# How to delete a message from the JMS queue

Tags: java, jms

Is there any API to delete a message from the JMS queue without using the monitoring admin tool.

Answer (score 11):

No direct API for deleting message. You can call queueReceiver.receive() method to remove a message from a queue. QueueBrowser will not remove messages from queue.

Answer (score 8):

I had to additionally call `session.commit()` for the consumer to delete messages.

Additionally, the `receivenowait` API doesn't work; call `receive(1000)` instead.

Here is a working piece of code I wrote that worked on `jboss`:

```
try {
  connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
  session = connection.createSession(true,-1);
  Queue queue = (Queue) QueueConnectionFactory.getInitialContext().lookup("/queue/DLQ");
  QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
  Enumeration<?> enum1 = browser.getEnumeration();

  while(enum1.hasMoreElements()) {
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage)enum1.nextElement();
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "JMSMessageID='" +  msg.getJMSMessageID()  + "'");
    //You can try starting the connection outside while loop as well, I think I started it inside while loop by mistake, but since this code worked I am hence letting you know what worked  
    connection.start();
    Message message = consumer.receive(1000) ;
    if ( message != null ) {
        //do something with message
    }
  }
} 
finally {
  session.commit();
  consumer.close();
  browser.close();
  session.close();
  connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is something I could get to work:

I am assuming you want to delete a message matching a particular criteria.

```
Queue destination = session.createQueue("your_q");

QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(destination);

Enumeration<?> enum1 = browser.getEnumeration();

while(enum1.hasMoreElements())
{
   TextMessage msg = (TextMessage)enum1.nextElement();
   if(msg.getStringProperty("any_prop").equals("some_prop"))
   {
       MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, "id='" +   msg.getStringProperty("id") + "'");
      consumer.receive(1000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A QueueBrowser object may be what you require. I think it has a delete method ( or similar )

Comment: I dont think there is a delete method in the QueueBrowser as far as read from the java docs ... Queue Browser is only used to read queue

Comment: You're right - but I remember using a QueueBrowser in this content. If I remember rightly I got the enumeration of the messages in the Queue, iterated over that, and consumed the message that I was interested in ( and just dod nothing with it )

Comment: Ok i will look through it ... but i have a small doubht can we change the headers of the message when they are in queue ... so that i can change the property "time_to_live"

Comment: one more doubht iam using p2p in which the destination is coded so how to consume message through queue browser

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I have actually tested successfully on weblogic:

destinationJNDI should contain the JNDI name of the queue, like "CommonJmsServer1@jms.jndi.dq.NL_Notifications.NLNotificationReprocessQ".

ctx should be a valid  InitialContext like:

```
 
  Properties env = new Properties();
  env.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, WL_USER);
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, WL_PASSWORD);
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, WL_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
  InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

idlist should be a CSV list of message IDs that you want to delete

this is the code:

```
 

  javax.jms.Queue queue = (javax.jms.Queue) ctx.lookup(destinationJNDI.toString());

  // lookup the queue connection factory
  QueueConnectionFactory queueConnFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(WEBLOGIC_JMS_XA_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
  // create a queue connection
  QueueConnection queueConn = queueConnFactory.createQueueConnection();
  queueConn.start();

  // create a queue session
  Session queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  for (String id : idlist.split(",")) {
      if (id.startsWith("ID:") ) {
        MessageConsumer consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue, " JMSMessageID='" +   id + "'");
        Message message = consumer.receive(1000);
        out.write("message = " + message + " ");
        out.write("deleted ID " + id + " ");
      }
  }
  queueSession.close();
  queueConn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanna just completed the above explanation to if you use transacation then you need commit and receive(1000). If you don't use transacation, then receivenowait withou commit.